# Reading CSV File using Numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
dataPoints = genfromtxt(temp.csv, dtype='datetime64[D],i8',delimiter=' ')
```

**CSV File: temp.csv**

```
2014-05-19 10
2014-05-20 11
2014-05-21 12
```

**Output from** `print(dataPoints)`

```
[ nan  10.]
[ nan  11.]
[ nan  12.]
```

**Edit**

```
[1969-12-31 00:00:00 1970-01-11 00:00:00]
[1969-12-31 00:00:00 1970-01-12 00:00:00]
[1969-12-31 00:00:00 1970-01-13 00:00:00]
[1969-12-31 00:00:00 1970-01-14 00:00:00]
[1969-12-31 00:00:00 1970-01-13 00:00:00]
```

Comment: perhaps because a date is not a number

Comment: @daouzli who said they all had to be numbers?

Comment: the `dtype` default value in the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tell NumPy what types to expect. E.g.:

```
>>> genfromtxt('temp.csv', dtype='datetime64[D],i8')
array([(datetime.date(2014, 5, 19), 10L),
       (datetime.date(2014, 5, 20), 11L), (datetime.date(2014, 5, 21), 12L)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<M8[D]'), ('f1', '<i8')])
```

Comment: As for "why" are you getting `nan` instead of the proper type... NumPy should figure out the types for each column on its own, but dates don't seem to be on their coercion list and it's probably getting confused by the fact that your string starts on a number.

Comment: after using your dtype I get the output in my edit above. This doesn't look right. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Maybe a different version of NumPy? Anyway, do you want to operate with the dates, or just read them? If you're happy with a plain string you can just use `"S10,i8"` instead. No need for `delimiter`

Comment: Also, `i8` may not be suitable for you. You may need to specify a larger integer

Comment: I would like to work with dates, so some kind of datetime would probably be ideal. How do I check the version of NumPy I'm using?